# Canonical question needed: Java's infamous ArrayList(int n)

Tags: discussion, canonical

We've got a few dozen or so Java questions floating around that are of the form:

> I've initialized my `ArrayList` with `new ArrayList<Object>(50)`, but the size is 0!  What's wrong with this?

...and it's getting a bit tiresome to see the same information repeated.

So, to that, I propose that we find a canonical question for this problem.  I'm going to put together a query that looks around for questions that are good candidates to be closed by it, but my recommendation for a canonical answer would be [Distinction between the capacity of an array list and the size of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27946920/1079354).

The reasons:

- The confusion around what `new ArrayList(int n)` does to begin with has to do with the distinction between initializing an array and initializing an `ArrayList`.
- The accepted answer does a great job of explaining why passing an `int` to an `ArrayList` does something different.

I'd be fine with any other question and answer if anyone has one, but I'm more or less interested in centralizing one place for this information.

Comment: I'd love to find out why there is some sentiment of disagreement, barring the usual, "Mercury is in retrograde" rationale that downvotes tend to carry.

Comment: Because people <3 dupe questions & dupe answers. Especially those of which comes with a rep-guarantee.

Comment: @Makoto: Perhaps because the question and answers are not well-voted (yet). I dunno. It seems reasonable enough to me, though.

Comment: Bonus rep if poster tries to call a method on a list item and gets a NRE too.

Comment: There's also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17301329/1743880) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11908037/1743880) but I don't find it better than the one you already have. [That one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4037359/1743880) also but it should be edited! Or maybe even [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15017318/1743880)... Lots of dupes indeed :D.

Comment: Can I write this? I would *love* a rep bonus. Just be sure to close everything else as a duplicate of mine :P

Comment: _"Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity"_ Taken from [the Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(int)) Why do we even need to handle this? Just close all of them.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Close all of them under what reason? They're valid questions

Comment: @Zizouz212:  I'm confident that at least one answer exists out there that addresses the problem, or I would have written it myself.  That said, if we can't seem to find a good dupe target, that may be the last recourse.

Comment: @Makoto You *will* let *me* write it right?

Comment: @Zizouz212:  Only if we can't find a suitable canonical answer that addresses the problem, which I genuinely believe there are at least a few.

Comment: You know this is close enough to be considered for .NET's `List<T>` type as well...

Comment: I can't classify these as good, reasonable or acceptable questions. The reason being: 10 years ago the java-novice me made the exact same mistake. But I then looked at the javadoc and knew where I was goofing in under a minute. I just cannot see questions that are the product of actively refusing to not inform yourself with readily available documentation as any kind of questions you want to keep.

Comment: @Gimby, the point of Stack Overflow is to provide readily available, easily searchable, documentation.  Documentation should *not* adhere to either Don't Repeat Yourself or Single Point Of Truth.

Comment: @EuanM I dare you to back that up, because the SO I know is about questions and answers that are well-researched.

Comment: Which point do you need backed up?

Comment: The fact that searchability is an important consideration for Stack Overflow and its answers?  Or the fact that DRY and SPOT are for instructions that humans give to computers, and not for guidance that humans give to other humans?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should write up a self-answered question with a very **detailed** and **comprehensive** combination of all the information about the question that would cover all the questions that could be asked about this.

Take care to cover any *edge* cases that people will use to claim their localized problem is not the same to cut down on burning close votes because of naive reopenings.

Then close all the existing questions that are partial answer duplicates as the duplicates of the new one.

Comment: The reason I'm strongly hesitant about this is because there are a lot of answers that cover this scenario already.  Several examples were already provided in a comment here.  In all honesty, the only edge case I could think of for this is, "This isn't an array - using a number doesn't mean what you think it does," which is the same advice being given out in several other answers.

Comment: Writing a single detailed and comprehensive combination of all the information might just cause yet another duplicate question to appear.  [Relevant](https://xkcd.com/927/)

Comment: I'd add a recommendation to also close all related posts as a dupe of the canonical one.

Comment: @Makoto How about a FAQ like answer that has short descriptions about each problem and links/guides to already written good questions/answers for more detail?

Comment: This answer is an **abuse** of moderator tools and **destructive** to SO. Your detailed and comprehensive guide will miss numerous edge cases because you will be closing many "partial answer duplicates" where the issue in the question is **not** related to the information in your guide. Every software developer knows that you can run into bizzare issues when you start running a technology stack with multiple dependencies. Your guide will never cover the majority of edge cases and many of those edge cases are highly upvoted, valuable Q/As.

Comment: @Mike then the questions are bad questions if they are so broad or such minor edge cases that they are so specific that that one specific users problem that they would useless to future visitors. So you are saying they should be closed and deleted for different reasons, either way the same end result, closed and probably deleted.

Comment: 1) Are you saying that questions that help a small number of people should be deleted? It's one thing to suggest that a wildly obscure question about a buried feature in a Java should be deleted, sure maybe that edge case should be marked as duplicate. But what about the questions that only help a small number of people because they use libraries or software that simply is not used widespread? Is it not valuable to help 5-10 future visitors if it can save them hours of headache? 2) Some of the "partial answer duplicates" are upvoted handsomely, meaning they help many people.

Comment: [Questions that are simple typo's that have absolutely nothing to do with the original question are useful to only one person, the person that made the typo. So yes, when the potential # of people helped is or approaches `1` it should be deleted because it is extremely narrow in scope and too localized to be any help to anyone in the future.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35303359/177800)

Comment: This is **exactly** the problem with your naive sweep to mark all these questions as duplicates. The question you linked was not about a simple typo. The error displayed in the question is erroneously thrown by the underlying library when an incorrect table name is passed to it. If you don't think anyone in the future will ever be baffled by a red herring error from Accumulo then you should delete it. Admittedly, very few people use Accumulo. But the point remains that many of the Q/As have been upvoted many times, indicating they are useful.